# Create a template page for html that can be used on every page

Tags: asp.net

I would like to build the equivalent of a _layouts.cshtml page that I can use with every page in my web app. I don't want to use cshtml or razor though I want to use html. Is there a simple way to convert the _layouts page to standard html and then include it with the other pages in the app?

I have inherited an app that uses cshtml, with a _layouts page for menus and some content styling used on each page. I can duplicate the content on every page, but would prefer to have a generic solution for it. The client does not want to use cshtml pages. Any java library, such as AngularJS that would provide tools is ok for me to use. I'm not a front-end guy and this is a relatively low budget operation where I'm working for free. TIA.

Comment: If you convert it into an HTML page, how do you plan to render sections? If you want to use HTML, then you are probably aiming for SPA application. You should use Angular or React for this.

Comment: @HuseinRoncevic I am intending to convert the app to spa. I'm trying to sort out how to separate the html. If you can tell me how to split the page using angularJS (v. 1.N), you've answered my question.

Comment: It'd be nice if people commented on why they down vote a question rather than hiding behind anonymity.

Answer (score 0):

i'm not familiar with .cshtml but on an html page you could use an iframe and update the contents of the iframe with different pages as needed.

you could also get external html and put it on the current page using jquery's get().

```
// get the contents of 'test.html' and put it into the 'result' element
// on the current page.

$.get("ajax/test.html", function(data) {
    $(".result" ).html( data );
    alert("Load was performed.");
});
```

Comment: I either misread the question or it was updated. not sure if this answer really applies any more.

Comment: The question was not edited. No worries, easy to do.